# How to extract attribute value of a method within an unreferenced assembly

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have wrote a C# unit test project, 'GameTest', which containing three test methods. And also I add a customized attribute 'IDAttribute' for each test method.

```
public class IDAttribute : Attribute
{
    public IDAttribute(int id)
    {
        ...
```

After that, I wrote another application which attempt to extract all test methods within GameTest

```
var x = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"GameTest.dll");
var types = x.GetTypes();

...
foreach unit test method we found as m [Type:MethodInfo]:
    var attrs = m.GetCustomAttributes(false);
    foreach (var x in attrs)
    {
        if (x is TestCategoryAttribute)
        {
             var value = (x as TestCategoryAttribute).TestCategories;
             Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", value);
        }
        else if (x is IDAttribute)
        {
            ...
```

The problem here is I could not write 'IDAttribute' directly since no definition for it [ I have not referenced GameTest.dll]. And we get nothing for IDAttribute if attempt to reference that dll.

However, I could see the ID value using Visual Studio 2010 watch function when debugging.

So, is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: you could try to reference the superclass instead. or just reference a RawType.. but that would be unconstructive, as you use var already..

Comment: If so,I could not get the value within IDAttribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use reflection to get attribute type and value:

```
foreach (var x in attrs)
{
    var attributeType = x.GetType();
    if (attributeType.FullName == "ClassLibrary1.IDAttribute") // also check for attributeType.Assembly == loaded assembly, if needed 
    {
        var id = (int)attributeType.GetProperty("ID").GetValue(x);
        Console.WriteLine(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or assign it to a `dynamic` variable. That removes the need for Reflection.

Answer (score 2):

As PashaPash says, you can use Reflection to grab the "ID" value, or you can use Dynamic:

```
foreach (var x in attrs)
{
    var attributeType = x.GetType();
    if (attributeType.FullName == "ClassLibrary1.IDAttribute") // also check for attributeType.Assembly == loaded assembly, if needed 
    {
        dynamic idAttribute = x;
        int id = idAttribute.ID;
    }
}
```